# Not able to connect to Amazon RDS from EC2 Django Instance

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I was deploying my Django Project on AWS (this is my first time doing this) after a lot of first time learning i got stuck at an error  :

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '****.*****.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (0)")

When i tried migrating my Django Project.I tried multiple solutions but none worked. I tried command mysql -u username -p password -h ****.********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com but this also returned and error.

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '*****.*********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (2)

UPDATE 2: I Tried using command on AWS Documentation mysql -h mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p which have -h before using -u and -p  and an input for ***Port*** this changed the error which seems like now the connection is not not able to reach the server which seems a reasonable and a better error than before.

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '******.******l2la.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)

**I read in question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858538/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-aws-rds) about this,they are talking about binding the instance to an IP.How can i do that if that could be the problem?**

UPDATE1:
Screenshots:
FIRST RDS INFORMATION
[image: RDS SS 1]
[image: RDS SS 2]

EC2 instance Information
[image: EC2 SS 1]
[image: EC2 SS 2]

SGs information

[image: launch Wizard SG]
If you require any log or information please feel free to ask in the comments.
Thanks

Comment: What about security groups of RDS?

Comment: @Marcin Security groups ( EC2 Security Group - Inbound sg-62b6d61b ) With sg-62b6d61b (default) at source and all Ports and Traffic in Inbound. For Outbound All Traffic and Ports are Open with Destination 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: What about manually connection to the RDS from instance using `mysql` client? Also nothing or its only DJanog specific issue?

Comment: @Marcin I tried putting in the command in Command Prompt , *mentioned in question* it give almost the same error.I am not able to connect to the database using any method be it either mysql -u username -p password -h ****.********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com or django project.

Comment: I see. Sorry, missed that. Instance and rds are in same VPC? Do you have any NACLs that could  black the connections on your subnets?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, They are on same VPC and I have no idea of what are NACLs ..

Comment: I guess you use default network access control lists. Default are good. Returning to SGs (security groups). The `sg-62b6d61b` is the one you use for the instance ?

Comment: @Marcin I am using ID: sg-******* (this is different than RDS)    name : launch-wizard-1 .Should i change that to the same sg-62b6d61b? There is no way i see that i can change it .. The security group sg-62b6d61b is also listed but in Instance it only shows the other one.

Comment: Can try. The SG for the RDS inbound should allow SG of the instance. You can have two SGs, but inbound for RDS should allow SG which you use for instance. In this case  RDS should allow traffic from SG launch-wizard-1.

Comment: @Marcin No Luck, Nothing Changed.. Adding sg-62b6d61b as the only security group actually kicked me out of SSH session so I added both the SGs now i can log in but no luck with Mysql RDS Connection.

Comment: Can you make screenshots of SGs for RDS and your instance or provide their details in the question? Its getting difficult to visualize how exactly are they setup.

Comment: @Marcin Added all the screenshots. Please check.

Comment: The screenshot of proposed change is [here](https://i.imgur.com/nCuNlfs.png). All check if all ports are available in the SG, as they are by default.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, All the ports are set to open in Inbound and outbound both. Also made the changed you proposed but that didn't change anything. (Reverted Back the changes now)

Comment: Don't have any more ideas for now. I replicated the setup, and I haven't encountered any issues with connecting to my test RDS from an instance. So it must be something else what is happening.

Comment: Double check your mysql host. In the question you write `mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` but in the screenshots its something else. I can replicate your error by using wrong host name in `mysql` command.

Comment: @Marcin That host is the sample host code provided in Documentation, I am using the correct host provided by RDS panel. How did you create and what is the command you are using to connect to your RDS ? I will just replicate the same then.. at least i will get a working db.

Comment: I created mysql rds and Amazon Linux 2 wilh all default settings in default VPC. Didn't change anything in Security Groups for both RDS and Instance.  The mysql command was same as yours `mysql -u admin -p  -h database-1.cm3c1syrcj06.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for all the help,The different SGs were the reasons it wasn't getting connected. The inbound of the RDS should be the SG used by your EC2 instance. I will update this question with the answer. I studied about SGs and how they work.. finally got it to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security group of Database should hold a Value in Inbound Rules :
[image: SG Db]

This Rule should allow connection from your EC2 Instance.Either set the IP Address or set the SG of EC2 Instance.
You can use **the Private IP of your instance rather than the Public IP** also.
*(Not sure about Security Concerns or Advantages.)*

> Update After a Year: Well you should use private IP and not the same security
> group.DB should only be accessible to the EC2 and not to public.